# What is the difference in PCRE pattern: `(?!or|and)\w+` and `[(?!or|and)\w]+`?

Tags: regex, pcre, pcregrep

What I want to capture is some variable/call expressions without `or` or `and` keywords.
As the title says, what is the difference between `(?!or|and)\w+` and `[(?!or|and)\w]+` ?
I'm sure those are different, because for the following pattern:

```py
...
if (var_select is False) or (var_select in SOME_GLOBAL_ARRAY):
...
```

`pcregrep -r 'if (?!or|and)\w+ is False'` fails to capture this pattern, but `pcregrep -r 'if [(?!or|and)\w]+ is False'` does.
What does `[...]` mean in the context of having `(?!...)` and `\w` together?

Comment: `[` starts a character set, so `[(?!or|and)\w]+` is probably nonsensical - it will match any of the characters inside.

Comment: `[ ]` is a custom *character class*. `\w` is a [predefined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef) character class, same as `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. In a character class, the characters `(`, `?`, `!`, `|`, and `)` have no special meaning, and specifying the same character multiple times is just redundant. Which means that `[(?!or|and)\w]` matches any of the following characters: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`, `(`, `)`, `?`, `!`, and `|`. --- In contrast, `(?!or|and)\w+` matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_`, as long as it doesn't *start with* `or` or `and`.

Comment: @Andreas Wow, thanks for your clarification. Indeed, when I tried the bracket pattern without `(` and `)`, it cannot capture the code.

Comment: @Andreas Then is it allowed to write `[\w()]+` to mean `[a-zA-Z_()]+`?

Comment: Yes, if you look in the **documentation** at the example [character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes), you will see that `[a-d[m-p]]` is a *union*, and is the same as `[a-dm-p]`. Since `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z_]`, that means that `[\w()]` is the same as `[[a-zA-Z_]()]` and therefore the same as `[a-zA-Z_()]`.

Comment: See https://www.regular-expressions.info/ to learn more about how regular expressions work, across languages.

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) also has information about several of your questions here, and pointers to more learning materials.